# no such file to load -- bundler/setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I'm trying to get Rails going on Rackspace Servers and, unfortunately, they don't do support for Rails. I am using Apache and Passenger (no RVM) on Ubuntu. When I hit the server, I got the following error:

> no such file to load -- bundler/setup

The traceback is as follows:

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in`require'
>   /rails/gradebook-attendance/config/boot.rb 6
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in`require'
>   /rails/gradebook-attendance/config/application.rb  1
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in`require'
>   /rails/gradebook-attendance/config/environment.rb  2
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in `gem_original_require'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb   31  in`require'
>   config.ru  3
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb  46  in `instance_eval'
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb  46  in`initialize'
>   config.ru  1   in `new'
>   config.ru  1

Bundler is definitely installed. When I execute gem list -d bundler, I get back

> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> bundler (1.0.17)
>      Authors: André Arko, Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
>      Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/bundler
>      Homepage: http://gembundler.com
>      Installed at: /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>      The best way to manage your application's dependencies

Also, running irb and typing "require 'bundler'" returns true.

$GEM_HOME points to a path that includes the bundler-1.0.17 gem.

I have also set RUBYOPT=rubygems

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have GEM_HOME set in your user space or are you using the SetEnv directive for apache.  If you have it set in something like your bash profile, then apache wont see that env variable.  In your vhost you may want to add something like:

```
SetEnv GEM_HOME /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Comment: I did it in user space, in my .bashrc. Thanks for the heads up on that.

I ended up just installing RVM and Ruby 1.9.2 and somehow it solved all my problems.